# Cant compile contracts with brownie because of this error: which: no solc in $PATH (on Gnu/Linux boxes) after a fresh install

Tags: brownie

After following the instructions to install Brownie using pipx (https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#installing-brownie) I was able to execute brownie (after adding ~/.local/bin to my $PATH) I was able to execute brownie but I noticed the following message:

```
which: no solc in ( ... my $PATH directories ...)
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, my system was missing the `solc` binary, which it's really easy to install if your Gnu/Linux distribution supports `snapd`. Since I use Fedora 34, I installed `solc` like this:

```
sudo snap install solc
```

https://snapcraft.io/install/solc/fedora

Once solc was installed, I was able to exec `brownie compile` with success.

Comment: it is better to get it from `Releases` section of Ethereum's Foundation github. You can download all the versions of it